# How to convert a string to an integer in a JSON file using jq?

Tags: json, casting, jq

I use jq to transform a complex json object into a tinier one. My query is:

```
jq 'to_entries[]| {companyId: (.key), companyTitle: (.value.title), companyCode: (.value.booking_service_code)}' companies.json
```

Now, the `(.key)` is parsed as a string, yet I want `companyId` to be a number.

My result currently looks like this:

```
{
  "companyId": "1337",
  "companyTitle": "Some company title",
  "companyCode": "oxo"
}
```

yet it should be like:

```
{
  "companyId": 1337,
  "companyTitle": "Some company title",
  "companyCode": "oxo"
}
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`jq` has inbuilt functions, you can pipe your key to [`tonumber`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions):

```
jq 'to_entries[]| {companyId: (.key)|tonumber, companyTitle: (.value.title), companyCode: (.value.booking_service_code)}' companies.json
```

As per the docs:

> `tonumber` The `tonumber` function parses its input as a number. It will
>   convert correctly-formatted strings to their numeric equivalent,
>   leave numbers alone, and give an error on all other input.
>
> `Example jq '.[] | tonumber' Input   [1, "1"] Output 1 1`

Comment: Anyway to do this while somehow handling null values?

Comment: @Canovice Please open a new question with that requirement. You can link this answer there.

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to turn my string (that converts to a float) to an integer.  I was looking for a 'toint' function, one doesn't exist.

```
jq --arg str "1.435" -n '$str|tonumber'
1.435
```

I threw a floor in there to make sure the number that was created was an integer:

```
jq --arg str "1.435" -n '$str|tonumber|floor'
1
```

This also properly converts the OP original data as well.  If you want to *guarantee* your result is an integer you will need to floor it.

Comment: Or perhaps `round`.