# Remove double quotes from part of string JQ

Tags: bash, jq

I’m having trouble removing double quotes from the date I pass in to JQ.
Any idea how I can do that? -r doesn’t seem to do the trick.

```
curl SOMETHING | jq -r --arg date $(date +"%s") '.payload.overallStatus | [$date, .totalTimeSpent, .totalRecords, .totalDuplicates]'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   607  100   607    0     0  10649      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10649
[
  "1594330317",
  15802,
  89004346,
  10
]
```

(I plan to add the | @csv option to convert the output to a line of csv)

Comment: `tonumber`, as per https://stackoverflow.com/q/48887711/3266847?

Comment: jq -r --arg date $(date +"%s") '.payload.overallStatus | [$date|tonumber, .totalTimeSpent, .totalRecords, .totalDuplicates]’ creates error 
jq: error (at <stdin>:22): Cannot index string with string "totalTimeSpent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tonumber`. You need to use parentheses not to change the context for the remaining elements of the array.

```
[($date | tonumber), .totalTimeSpent, .totalRecords, .totalDuplicates]
```

Without the parentheses, the expression is equivalent to

```
[$date | (tonumber, .totalTimeSpent, .totalRecords, .totalDuplicates)]
```