# Convert types from strings to ints in newline delimited JSON file

Tags: json, type-conversion, ndjson

According to [How to preserve integer data type when exporting to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462987/how-to-preserve-integer-data-type-when-exporting-to-json), it is not currently possible to preserve integer types when exporting from BigQuery to JSON. This minor detail about BigQuery --> GCS JSON exports has been causing us many problems. The result of one of our table exports is a newline-delimited JSON that looks like this:

```
{"leagueId": "1", "name": "the ballers"}
{"team": "2", "leagueId": "1", "name": "the hoopers"}
{"team": "3", "leagueId": "1", "name": "the gamerrs"}
{"team": "4", "leagueId": "1", "name": "the drivers"}
{"team": "5", "leagueId": "1", "name": "the jumpers"}
{"team": "6", "leagueId": "1", "name": "the riserss"}
```

**team, leagueId** should both be ints, and we'd like to modify this NDJSON converting these strings back into its. The output we're going for is:

```
{"leagueId": 1, "name": "the ballers"}
{"team": 2, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the hoopers"}
{"team": 3, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the gamerrs"}
{"team": 4, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the drivers"}
{"team": 5, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the jumpers"}
{"team": 6, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the riserss"}
```

Assuming we know / have a list/array of the columns that need to be converted from strings into ints [team, leagueId], how can we do this conversion? Is this possible with (a) a bash command using a tool like `jq`, or (b) is there some python solution? Our full NDJSON is ~10GB in size, and performance is important as this is a step in our daily data-ingestion pipeline.

**Edit:** [How to convert a string to an integer in a JSON file using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887711/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-a-json-file-using-jq) - trying to use this post to help. Have come up with `jq '.team | tonumber' tmp/testNDJSON.json`, but this simply returns `1 2 3 4 5 6`, not an updated JSON, and only handles one key, not multiple keys.

**Edit2:** `jq -c '{leagueId: .leagueId | tonumber, team: .team | tonumber, name: .name}' tmp/testNDJSON.json > tmp/new_output.json` this *would* work if not for the missing `team` value in the first JSON... getting closer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if`

```
jq -c 'if .team then {leagueId: .leagueId | tonumber, team: .team | tonumber, name: .name} 
                else {leagueId: .leagueId | tonumber, name: .name} end '
```

more conditionals https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#ConditionalsandComparisons